# Click on show more button multiple times untill disabled-Protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

There is a button on the webpage called 'show more' which returns results in phases & user has to keep clicking it untill its faded away returning all the results.

I tried to do it thorugh while loop but i am getting error 'FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory'

Below is the code:

```
while(true) {
        browser.isElementPresent(element(by.id('toasten'))).then(function(Displayed){
                 console.log("Value of the promise "+Displayed);
            if (Displayed==true){
            element(by.id('toasten')).click();
            browser.sleep(5000).then(function(){console.log("sleep added");}); 
            }
        }); 

        }
```

The instances of how many times the show_more button will appear is not fixed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach it with *recursion* exiting once the element is not present:

```
var showMore = function () { 
    var button = element(by.id('toasten'));
    browser.isElementPresent(button).then(function(isPresent) {
        if (isPresent) {
            button.click();
            browser.sleep(5000);
            showMore();
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }); 
}
```

Note that you can also improve the logic inside the function and replace the `browser.sleep()` call with a more appropriate [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) waiting for the element to be present.

Comment: Note that recursion must be used instead instead of a while loop because promises are resolving. While/for loops are good for synchronous things, but not for asynchronous things.